# Regex Replacement BackReferences For Multiple Folders

Tags: regex

Given the following string:

```
/dh-jh-ng-fdhfjfk/djd-gkgi/700194015/image/test.png
```

Using:

```
^/[A-Za-z\-]+/[A-Za-z\-]+/[0-9{9}]/?(.*)?
```

I get the following backreferences:

```
R0: /dh-jh-ng-fdhfjfk/djd-gkgi/700194015/image/test.png
R1: 700194015/image/test.png
```

I need R1 to be:

```
R1: /image/test.png
```

"/image/test.png" can be any folder, multiple folders, any file, or none, in which case I need a single forward slash. How can I do this?

Note: This is for IIS re-write rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get out of the range quantifier `{9}`  from the character class , `[{9}]` would match a single character from the given list that is it matches `{` or `9` or `}`.

```
^/[A-Za-z\-]+/[A-Za-z\-]+/[0-9]{9}(/?.*)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kS8oG3/1)